# How does Android Auto Wifi Connect algorithm work?

Tags: android, algorithm, gps, wifi, android-wifi

How does the auto wifi connect algorithm work on the Android phone? For ex: when I go home, it auto-connects to my home network. When I step into Starbucks, it automatically connects to the Starbucks network. I assume there is a "background service" running on the phone at all times. Is this true?

1. If so, does this service constantly check the **GPS** location and then try to simply connect to the local network that was last inside that GPS coordinate?
2. Or, does the service automatically try to **find** any local network and simply connect to the first one that it is able to connect to?
3. Or, does it automatically connect to the **most frequently** connected network? Does auto wifi take into account the # of times it has connected to each network?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a programming question? If not, I'll vote to close. In answer to your 3 points though... 1: No. 2: Yes. 3: No.